# Error message saying "expected primary-expression before 'for'"

Tags: c++

So, my simple program calculates an employees total salary which is $200 + commission. The commission is 9% of their gross sales. So, the program asks for the gross sale of an employee and keeps asking until I use sentinel to stop.

Then I display the number of people that recieved salaries in a certain set of range, and then use asterisks to mark how many people recieved salaries in said range. Finally I also display the total salary by adding recieved salary and total commission by adding all the commissions. Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int SENTINEL = -1;

int main(){

int salary = 200, total_salary_employee, total_salary=0, gross, commission, total_commission=0, counter[9];
int i;



while(gross != SENTINEL){

    cout << "Enter gross sale for employee (-1 to stop): ";
    cin >> gross;

    if(gross == SENTINEL) break;

    if(gross < SENTINEL){
        cout << "\nError!\nPlease enter a correct value.\n" << endl;
        continue;
    }

    else{

        commission =  0.09 * gross;
        total_salary_employee = salary + commission;

        total_salary += total_salary_employee;
        total_commission += commission;

        if((total_salary > 200) && (total_salary < 300)){
            counter[1] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary >= 300) && (total_salary < 400)){
            counter[2] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary >= 400) && (total_salary < 500)){
            counter[3] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary >= 500) && (total_salary < 600)){
            counter[4] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary >= 600) && (total_salary < 700)){
            counter[5] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary >= 700) && (total_salary < 800)){
            counter[6] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary >= 800) && (total_salary < 900)){
            counter[7] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary >= 900) && (total_salary < 1000)){
            counter[8] += 1;
        }
        else{
            counter[9] += 1;
        }

    }


};

cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------";
cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "Element\t\t" << "# of Persons\t\t" << "Histogram";
cout << "\n";
cout << "$200 - $299\t\t" << counter[1] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[1]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$300 - $399\t\t" << counter[2] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[2]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$400 - $499\t\t" << counter[3] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[3]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$500 - $599\t\t" << counter[4] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[4]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$600 - $699\t\t" << counter[5] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[5]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$700 - $799\t\t" << counter[6] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[6]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$800 - $899\t\t" << counter[7] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[7]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$900 - $999\t\t" << counter[8] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[8]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$1000 and above\t\t" << counter[9] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[9]; i++){ cout << "*"; };

cout << "\nTotal salary: " << total_salary;
cout << "\nTotal commission: " << total_commission;



return 0;
```

}

Problem I'm having says:

> [Error] expected primary-expression before 'for'

and

> [Error] expected ';' before 'for'

and

> [Error] expected ';' before ')' token

Expected output:

Element..............# of person..............Histogram

$200-$299...............8...........................********

and the list goes on like that. The number 8 is only an example and the dots are to show that the output is in table form I don't know how to space them properly using this editor.

Can you please show me where and what my mistake is? And what would be a better and shorter way to write this?

Edited code for the `for` loop:

```
cout << "$200 - $299\t\t" << counter[1] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[1]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$300 - $399\t\t" << counter[2] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[2]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$400 - $499\t\t" << counter[3] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[3]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$500 - $599\t\t" << counter[4] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[4]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$600 - $699\t\t" << counter[5] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[5]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$700 - $799\t\t" << counter[6] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[6]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$800 - $899\t\t" << counter[7] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[7]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$900 - $999\t\t" << counter[8] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[8]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$1000 and above\t\t" << counter[9] << "\t\t";
for(int i = 0; i < counter[9]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
```

Answered. Thanks everyone.

Comment: if you indented your code properly, you would at least have a chance to understand your own code when trying to debug it.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `};`?

Comment: Indent your code using some tool like [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/). Use a good editor (like [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or `vim`) which is able to match opening and closing parenthesis and braces. Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: You forgot to initialise `gross`.

Comment: @npinti That's the opening and closing braces for my `for` statements. Assuming you're talking about those.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant What do you mean by intend, actually?

Comment: @nisyedlah: Try removing the extra `;` at the end.

Comment: @nisyedlah  He said indent, not intend.

Comment: @Poldie typo. Still, what does that mean?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I hope he meant he made a typo, but I've no idea why his instinct wasn't to google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to `cout` a `for` loop:

```
cout << "$200 - $299\t\t" << counter[1] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[1]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
```

...but it's not possible to do that. Instead, break the output down - single strings can be output using `cout << "something";`, and anything inside of the `for` loop can be output separately, as shown in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { cout << "*"; };
}
```

You can run this example online [here](http://codepad.org/OoMVHV6f).

Comment: @nisyedlah I see that you've added some text to your question to indicate that your problem is now resolved. If this answer was helpful, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A for-loop can not be used as a variable.

Replace

```
cout << "$200 - $299\t\t" << counter[1] << "\t\t" << for(i = 0; i < counter[1]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
```

with

```
cout << "$200 - $299\t\t" << counter[1] << "\t\t"; for(i = 0; i < counter[1]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indices in C++ are **zero-based**, for an array of `N` elements the valid indices are `0..N-1`.

You've defined your array as

```
int counter[9];
```

Your array has `9` elements so the valid indices are `0..8`, in your code you use `1..9`. The index `9` is past the end of the array and reading or writing past the end of an array is undefined behavior.

You need to change your code to only use indices `0..8`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did a lot of things wrong in my code, but thanks to GoBusto for his answer.

Here's the edited, final, and working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int SENTINEL = -1;

int main(){

int total_salary_employee = 0, total_salary = 0, gross, commission, total_commission=0, counter[9] = {0};

while(gross != SENTINEL){

    cout << "Enter gross sale for employee (-1 to stop): ";
    cin >> gross;

    if(gross == SENTINEL) break;

    if(gross < SENTINEL){
        cout << "\nError!\nPlease enter a correct value.\n" << endl;
        continue;
    }

    else{

        commission =  0.09 * gross;
        total_salary_employee = 200 + commission;

        total_salary += total_salary_employee;
        total_commission += commission;

        if((total_salary_employee > 200) && (total_salary_employee < 300)){
            counter[1] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary_employee >= 300) && (total_salary_employee < 400)){
            counter[2] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary_employee >= 400) && (total_salary_employee < 500)){
            counter[3] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary_employee >= 500) && (total_salary_employee < 600)){
            counter[4] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary_employee >= 600) && (total_salary_employee < 700)){
            counter[5] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary_employee >= 700) && (total_salary_employee < 800)){
            counter[6] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary_employee >= 800) && (total_salary_employee < 900)){
            counter[7] += 1;
        }
        else if((total_salary_employee >= 900) && (total_salary_employee < 1000)){
            counter[8] += 1;
        }
        else{
            counter[9] += 1;
        }

    }


};

cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------";
cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "Element\t\t" << "# of Persons\t\t" << "Histogram";
cout << "\n";
cout << "$200 - $299\t\t" << counter[1] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[1]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$300 - $399\t\t" << counter[2] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[2]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$400 - $499\t\t" << counter[3] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[3]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$500 - $599\t\t" << counter[4] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[4]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$600 - $699\t\t" << counter[5] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[5]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$700 - $799\t\t" << counter[6] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[6]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$800 - $899\t\t" << counter[7] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[7]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$900 - $999\t\t" << counter[8] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[8]; i++){ cout << "*"; };
cout << "\n";
cout << "$1000 and above\t\t" << counter[9] << "\t\t"; for(int i = 1; i <= counter[9]; i++){ cout << "*"; };

cout << "\n";
cout << "\nTotal salary: " << total_salary;
cout << "\nTotal commission: " << total_commission;

return 0;

}
```

I messed up in the counter checking too, where I put `total_salary` when it should have been `total_salary_employee` and I also initialized my counter array to `0`. Lastly I decided to just discard the salary variable and just add 200 to the commission. Thanks to everyone who tried to help! Much appreciated.

Comment: You still haven't initialised `gross`, so there's at least one bug still to be fixed.

Comment: ...and you're still accessing past the end of your array.